# Resizing main partition on existing installation, fdisk detects the free space but does not allow me to expand

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk

I am running the following command to expand my partition following the tips from this article [article](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/extend-resize-primary-partition-non-lvm-linux/)

Partition 7 (75Gb, starting at sector 1794791424) is my main one and 8 (100Gb, starting at sector 1580881920) is the extra space (there is clearly a gap between the two sectors which could cause the problem?).

I firstly run `fdisk: d` and delete partitions 7 and 8, then `fdisk: n` to create a new one.

As you can see from the terminal output below, it allows me to pick an spot in the sector range I just freed, but when I do, it does not allow me to use all the free space:

`Partition number (7-128, default 7):`

`First sector (1580881920-1953525134, default 1580881920):`

`Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (1580881920-1790597119, default 1790597119):`

The partition table:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1085439    1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1085440    1290239     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3    1290240    1323007      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4    1323008 1580881919 1579558912 753.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1790597120 1792694270    2097151  1024M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p7 1794791424 1953523710  158732287  75.7G Linux filesystem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the space of partition 8 for partition 7, because partition 8 was between
partition 4 and 5:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1085439    1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1085440    1290239     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3    1290240    1323007      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4    1323008 1580881919 1579558912 753.2G Microsoft basic data
               1580881920 1790597119                   ### free space of partition 8 ###
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1790597120 1792694270    2097151  1024M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p7 1794791424 1953523710  158732287  75.7G Linux filesystem
```

You would have to move partition 5 "to the top" first so that this partition starts at 1580881920.
After that you can resize partition 7 to take the remaining space.

Maybe it's easier to boot from a Linux Live CD and use [gparted](https://gparted.org/) for these two operations.

It's also not clear why you have two EFI System Partitions. One would suffice for Windows and Linux.